# How to split two papers that Google Scholar incorrectly thinks are the same paper?

Tags: google-scholar

For some reason I don't understand, Google Scholar thinks two of my papers are the same, despite different titles, co-authors, and publication years. When I click on one ("Resonant absorption as mode conversion?") it lists 27 versions, most of which are the completely different paper ("Three Dimensional MHD Wave Propagation and Conversion to Alfvén Waves near the Solar Surface. I"). It therefore combines the citations for the two. How can I split them? I even tried deleting both papers and adding them manually from scratch, but without success.

Comment: Why don't you contact google scholar directly?

Comment: @Memming: Because no identifiable human beings work at Google?  Could that be why?

Comment: I reported a similar issue multiple times without success. I also deleted both my papers and added them as new. The day after scholar merge them again and again. I have the correct pdf on researchgate and academia. But scholar keeps merging them

Comment: Has anyone tried to delete articles from Google Scholar and add them again - as suggested above ? - What about the titles - in my friend's case these are identical but all the other details are different. Moreover, the 2017 paper is a review in a monograph/book and the 2014 paper is a standard journal paper. Unfortunately, both have been published - someone has asked about it.
The review paper (2017) has no citations yet, but the research/journal paper (2014) has already got 5 citations. On the Google Scholar list the papers are listed one after the other with the same number of citations but

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/60346)

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/60346)

Answer (score 21):

By now, there is an option when editing the merged GoogleScholar article's version as shown in the example below. Ensure you are logged in as the article's author.

1. Open the "edit your article" e.g., via clicking on the asterisk right to the number of citations in the list of your articles. Alternatively, open your article's page on GoogleScholar, where you press the edit button.

[image: Merged citations are marked with an asterisk]

2. The option is called "Unmerge this article and add it to my profile as a separate entry."

[image: Edit article and choose to unmerge this article]

Usually, there is a star on the right hand side of a merged article. If there is not, just add a new entry.

Comment: At least when I tried unmerging, I could not correctly separate the "versions" that were a different paper, nor do I think this effected anything but a temporary change, and possibly that only in my personal profile.  Have you had better luck with unmerging?

Comment: @Kimball: With this I have no experience but if others did, please tell...

Comment: @Kimball did you manage to fix this? I'm facing the same problem

Comment: @Khaledvic unfortunately, no

Comment: I don't see thin unmerging option in my case, unfortunately.

Comment: @QuestionEverything I hope my latest change helps you find the edit window.

Answer (score 14):

You can report the error at the following link:

https://support.google.com/scholar/contact/general

Comment: FYI I reported a similar issue some time ago, which was never addressed.  But perhaps if enough people start reporting these, then they'll start fixing them...

Comment: There should be one thread entitled "Google Scholar", this should be the only answer, and every new question about the website can be closed as a duplicate. One can dream.

Comment: This link no longer works.

Answer (score -3):

"unmerge" in GoogleScholar is not possible.
SOLUTION: delete the [merged articles] noted with *, then add them separately ;-)
it worked for me.. 
Good luck!!

Comment: You are aware that the question is three years old and states: *I even tried deleting both papers and adding them manually from scratch, but without success.*

Comment: @skymnigen The former is not an issue; in fact, this website encourages users to address old questions with improved answers. The latter is the dealbreaker here, indeed.