# How can an Error in Google Scholar be corrected?

Tags: publications, google-scholar

The bibliographic data of an article of mine is confused with that of a book with the same title. Not so long ago the book was confused with another article of the same year, thereby cancelling the citations. How to correct and restore?

Comment: The solutions from [How to split two papers that Google Scholar incorrectly thinks are the same paper?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/38779/17254) might work.

Comment: The general answer to "How to do x with Google Scholar" is "with great difficulty" - I don't think Google care much about Scholar, as it doesn't make them any money. There is a support form at https://support.google.com/scholar/contact/general. If you are lucky you might get a response.

Comment: I can attest to google scholar answering requests for help. But they were often not willing or able to fix problems I described.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, make sure that the place where Google Scholar is getting the data from has it listed correctly. They scrape from other sources and there's a mistake in the source, then there will be a mistake in Google Scholar as well.

Then you should try to contact them and let them know of the mistake. Even though the chance to get it corrected might be low (Google Scholar isn't as highly prioritized for Google as some of their other services), it is still worth a try.